# Non-container based java remoting?

Tags: java, web-services, rmi, hessian

We're trying to design a new addition to our application. Basically we need to submit very basic queries to various remote databases accessed over the internet and not owned or controlled by us.

Our proposal is to install a small client app on each of the foreign systems, tiered in 2 basic layers, 1 that is tailored to the particular database its talking to, to handle the actual query in SQL or whatever, the other tier would be the communication tier to handle incoming requests and send back responses. This communication interface would be the same over all of the foreign systems, ie all requests and responses have the same structure.

In terms of java remoting I guess this small client app would be the 'server' and our webapp (normally referred to as the server) is the 'client'.

I've looked at various java remoting solutions (Hessian, Burlap, RMI, SOAP/REST WebServices). However am I correct in thinking that with all of these the 'server' must run in a container, ie in a tomcat/jetty etc instance?

I was really hoping to avoid having to battle all the IT departments controlling the foreign systems to get them to install very much. The whole idea is that its thin/small/easy to install/pain free. Are there any solutions that do not require running in a container / webserver?

The communication really is the smallest part of this design, no more than 10 string input params (that have no meaning other than to the db) and one true/false output. There are no complex object models required. The only complexity would be from security/encryption etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wamly suggest somethig based on Jetty, the embedded HTTP server. You package a simple runnable JAR with dependency JARs into a ZIP file, add a startup script, and you have your product. See for example [here](http://caprazzi.net/posts/simple-webserver-and-rest-with-jetty-and-no-xml/).

Comment: This could be exactly the compromise we've been looking for. Thanks for the tip. Also to other answers that were very similar.

Answer (score 1):

I often use Sprint-Remoting in my projects and here you find a description how to use without a container. The guy is starting the jetty from within his application:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?12852-HttpInvoker-without-web-container

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/remoting.html

Regards,

Boskop

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most of them runs a standard servlet container. But containers like Jetty have very low footprint and you may [configure and run Jetty completely out of your code](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty) while you stay with servlet standards.

Do not fail to estimate initial minimal requirements that may grow with project enhancement over time. Then have a standard container makes things much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged this question with [rmi], RMI does not require any form of container. All you need is the appropriate TCP ports to be open.